# Changed name of an project and now my manifest is not right

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-studio

I copied my project and re-named it using refractor in order to create a second version of my app that I can put ads in.

I can not build it because I now have an error in my android manifest on this line:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

It gives an error of:

URI is not registered

Full Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliofree"
          android:versionCode="9"
          android:versionName="1.7" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android ">

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="11"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <!-- Permission to write to external storage -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/bp_logo"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/orangeTheme">
        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.BeerPage"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.BreweryPage"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.StylePage"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.LogIn"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.Search"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.TasteTags"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.StatisticsPage"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.BreweryStatistics"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.StyleStatistics"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.TasteStatisticsPage"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.BreweryPage2"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.StylePage2"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.TastePage"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.TopTastes"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.YourTopTaste"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.TastePage2"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.BeerPage2"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.BreweryPage3"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.TasteTags2"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.BreweryAllBeersPage"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.BreweryTopBeers"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.BreweryYourTopBeers"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.StyleTopBeers"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.StyleTopBeers2"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.StyleYourTopBeers"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.beerportfoliofree.StyleYourTopBeers2"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Post the full manifest file.

Comment: I've never seen the `xmlns:xsi` and `xsi:schemaLocation` attributes in an Android manifest before. Try removing them.

Comment: Maybe its from android studio?

Comment: You didn't state if you are using Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans, Ant, Maven, Gradle, or some other thing to build your app. At any rate, an xsi:schemaLocation attribute requires list of pairs of values in the quoted attribute string; each pair havng an xmlns namespace string and the physical location of the schema ".xsd" (that's why it's called schemaLocation).